# Is it possible to use arbitrary middleware in specific controller or ever method in asp.net web api2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, middleware

I have a bunch of already written middlewares. As i know they can easily be used at global pipeline level.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Portal.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder)
        {   
            builder
                .UseApiResponseCompression()
                ....
        }
    }
}
```

But i really excited hypothetical opportunities to use this middleware in appropriate controller or method ( I've seen such functionality implementation in asp.net core)

**Q:** Is it possible to use arbitrary middleware in specific controller or ever method ( like filters) in asp.net web api2?

Answer (score 0):

Will [`MiddlewareFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) do what you are expecting?

You create a pipeline class, say `MyPipeline`, which has one method with signature  `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)`. Then place `[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(MyPipeline))]` on the controller or action.

Comment: Middleware filters works with asp.net core. I am searching things with same functionality, but that works with asp.net ( .net framework) web api 2. Thx for you attention!